# Nginx config: redirect

Tags: redirect, nginx, configuration, regular-language, nginx-location

I'm having some difficulties figuring out my how to redirect in my `nginx.config` file.

I would like to redirect from:
`http://domain.com/content/uploads/2016/06/img.jpg`

to:
`http://cdn.domain.com/uploads/2016/06/img.jpg`

Add the "cdn." before the domain and cut out "content/".

I managed to add "cdn.":

```
location ~* ^/content/uploads/.*$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @cdn-domain;
}

location @cdn-domain{
    return 301 $scheme://cdn.domain.co.il$request_uri;
}
```

But how do I cut out "content/" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

302

```
rewrite ^/content/uploads/(.*)$ http://cdn.domain.com/uploads/$1 redirect;
```

301

```
rewrite ^/content/uploads/(.*)$ http://cdn.domain.com/uploads/$1 permanent;
```

For more: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html